# How does functional programming work at the assembly level?

Tags: assembly, x86, compiler-construction

my current project is to make a small compiler, for fun.
Currently it is able to generate code for subroutine calls.

I want to enable functional programming in my language.
But i stumbled upon the problem, that i do not know the address of the label (in the code segment) where the function is which i am passing on the stack. can nasm calculate it for me? how is this handled in other functional languages?

```
Int main(){subr2(subr);} Int subr2(Int() myfn){return myfn();} Int subr(){return 1;}
```

How would this (nonsensical) code be translated?
I tried to make the smallest example i could.

The problem i see is that you do not know the offset in the code segment of the label (which gets removed by the assembler?) as a compiler that *only* compiles down until the assembly level.

How can this be solved without much overhead?

Thanks for your time !

EDIT:
@Jester pointed out that you can push labels on the stack in assembly

Comment: Not sure what your problem is? It's not your job to fill in offsets, the assembler and linker do that for you. You just use a label.

Comment: @Jester i cannot use a label, because i want to pass a reference to the function on the stack. i am not sure if you can push labels on the stack?

Comment: Of course you can. Why couldn't you?

Comment: @Jester you just solved my problem! Thanks :)

Comment: While your specific question has been addressed, it should be noted that there's more to passing around first-class functions in functional languages than just passing around the functions' addresses: closures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Int main() {
    subr2(subr);
}

Int subr2(Int() myfn) {
    return myfn();
}

Int subr() {
    return 1;
}
```

Would (without any optimization, and assuming the calling convention isn't awful) become:

```
main:
  mov eax, subr
  call subr2
  ret

subr2:
    call eax
    ret

subr:
    mov eax,1
    ret
```

With optimization; first you'd inline the `subr2()` into `main()` to get this:

```
Int main() {
    temp = subr;
    return temp();
}

Int subr() {
    return 1;
}
```

Then you'd do some "constant propogation" to get this:

```
Int main() {
    return subr();
}

Int subr() {
    return 1;
}
```

Then you'd inline the `subr()` into `main()` to get this:

```
Int main() {
    return 1;
}
```

Then you'd end up with this:

```
main:
    mov eax,1
    ret
```

Note that `main()` is just a normal function. Typically there's start-up code that the linker injects into an executable file that initializes things (standard library, heap, etc), calls `main()`, and then does `exit()` if `main()` returns.

Comment: Or if inlining wasn't possible (e.g. the function-pointer wasn't a compile-time constant), then you'd optimize the `call eax` / `ret` tailcall into `jmp eax` in subr2.

Answer (score -1):

@Jester had the solution.
Indeed you can push labels to the stack in assembly.

Example code:

```
   section  .text

   global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

   _start:              ;tells linker entry point

   push subr ; pushing label on stack
   pop eax ; 
   push _start_continue; together these 2 should make a 'call'
   jmp eax    ;

   _start_continue:

   mov eax,1; sys_exit
   int 0x80;

   subr:

   mov  edx,len     ;message length
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   ret;
```

Comment: You can just use `jmp subr` like a normal person; there's no need to `push imm32`/`pop eax` and then `jmp eax`.  Also, you can use `call subr` to push the return address for you.  None of this demonstrates passing a function pointer to another function.  (Which you can do by using a label; label addresses are link-time constants so they can be filled in by the linker into either absolute (`mov reg, label`) or relative (`jmp label`) references)